# HLS stream is not working with react-native-video

Tags: amazon-web-services, http-live-streaming, mediaelement, react-native-video, aws-media-live

I am trying to embed live stream using `react-native-video` packages, but HLS link is not working, please help

Comment: "not working"  is not specific. What exactly is happening? Any errors? What is your current setup?

Comment: For tips on asking a good question, please see: [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Its just not showing anything, no errors

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for contacting AWS support. May I know what error did you see? And yes, can you playback the stream on other players?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest testing the same playback URL with other players such as shaka, bitmovin, safari, VLC or ffplay.  If the source URL works in most or all of those players, then the issue is most likely related to the implementation of the react player.